# Removing bracket in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, brackets, biblatex-philosophy

[image]

Referring to the image above, I'm trying to remove the bracket for articles having neither volume nor number. I am using `biblatex-philosophy` with its `volnumformat=parens`. There is no other simple guide for me in the manual except to undertake the difficult coding of which I don't understand yet. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is the code for your reference.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,backend=biber,volnumformat=parens]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Russell,
  keywords = {article},
  title={Article without volume and number},
    journal={Journal of journaling},
  author={Russell, Bertrand},
  year={1900},
}
@article{Wittgenstein,
  keywords = {article},
  title={Article with volume and number},
  author={Wittgenstein, Ludwig},
  journal={Journal of journaling},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  year={1950},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-philosophy` doesn't check if a `volume` field is supplied, it just assumes there to be one, we can add that back in

```
\renewbibmacro*{volnumparens}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ not test {\iffieldundef{volume}} or not test {\iffieldundef{number}} }
    {\nopunct%
     \printtext[pureparens]{%
       \printfield{volume}%
       \setunit*{\volnumpunct}%
       \printfield{number}}}
    {}}
```